# PHP Exec command won't run untill apache is restarted

Tags: php, apache, debian, exec, imagick

I have a php script that executes a command. This script has been working for months if not years. Since the upgrade to debian 9, every day it stops working. If I restart apache, it will work again for the full day, then will stop working the day after... untill I restart apache, and so on !

I wrote a very simple test script:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

exec('/usr/bin/convert -density 600 /var/www/mysite/var/tmp/etiquette_20181019_071109_991362.pdf[0] -quality 75 /var/www/mysite/var/tmp/etiquette_20181015_110715_817744.pdf.test.jpeg', $output, $return);

var_dump($return);
var_dump($output);

echo shell_exec('echo SHELL EXEC');
echo exec('echo EXEC',$return,$output);
echo 'done';
```

When I call the URL, the result is:

```
int(1) array(0) { } SHELL EXEC EXECdone
```

but the file /var/www/mysite/var/tmp/etiquette_20181015_110715_817744.pdf.test.jpeg is NOT CREATED. (the page is displayed instantly, indicating that convert command has probably not ran at all....)

Then I just do /etc/init.d apache2 restart, then call the url again. The output is the same BUT now the file has been created (the page takes up to 5 or 10 seconds during the image conversion), and it will keep working untill the day after. This has been reproduced every day for 5 days now...

Any clue on how to diagnose this problem would be much appreciated.

Comment: Enable error logging (`ini_set('error_reporting',E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',true);`) or check error log (location of error_log can be found in `phpinfo()`). Let's start from this point

Comment: Thanks for advice, but that was the purpose of the 2 lines in script: error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
Although different than yours, they seemed correct to me ? I can't see any error on the page...

Comment: Hi first, you need to interchange the placement of ini_set and error_reporting. Reason being if your INI is not set you will not be able to see the Errors though your error_reporting is on or not. you will have to use error log, though that will just show any php errors. For you to find out what is holding the file creation check what you get in terminal if you run your file is there any issue with folder permission. or you may need to keep some wait for file to write and then get stored.

Comment: I have interchanged lines 1 and 2... same result no error output.

a) running php test.php, does work
b) calling https://site/test.php does not produce the file
c) restarting apache2 then calling https://site/test.php does work (... and will stop working after 1 day...)

I'm completely confused...

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Did you find a solution?